# How to show that the map $ R $ here is measure-preserving

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-dynamical-systems

Assume that $ (X,\mathcal{B},m,T) $ is a measure-preserving dynamical system, where $ (X,\mathcal{B},m) $ is a probability space, $ \mathcal{B} $ denotes all the measurable sets in $ X $, $ m $ is the measure on it and $ T $ is a measure-preserving map, i.e. for any $ B\in\mathcal{B} $, we have $ m(T^{-1}B)=m(B) $. Assume that $ E\subset X $ satisfies that $ m(E)>0 $ and $$
\tau(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&+\infty&x\in E_0,\\
&\min\{k\geq 1:T^kx\in E\}&x\notin E_0,
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
where $ E_0:=\{x\in E:T^kx\notin E,\,\,\forall k\geq 1\} $, which is the where known first hitting time. By using the famous Poincaré returning theorem, $ m(E_0)=0 $. Also, by carefully check the proof of Poincaré returning theorem, there is $ F\subset E $ such that $ m(F)=m(E) $, $ T^{-1}F=F $ and $ \tau $ is finite everywhere in $ F $. Then we can define a map $ R $ given by
$$
R:F\to F\quad(x\mapsto T^{\tau(x)}x).
$$
I want to show that $ R $ is measure-preserving. For fixed $ A\subset F $, I want to decompose $ A $ into $ A_1 $ and $ A_2 $ depending on whether the first hitting point in $ E $ is in $ A $ or not. Since $ m(A_1)+m(A_2)=m(A) $, it remains to consider the set $ A_2 $, where the difficulties arise. Can you give me some hints or references?

Comment: I think that there is a typo somewhere . You are saying that $F$ is $T$-invariant  and has the same measure as $E$. If $T$  were ergodic  than this would  imply that $E$ is either negligible or of full measure.  The Poincaré recurrence does not require ergodicity.

Comment: The map $T^{\tau(x)}$ was introduced by Kakutani in 1943.  For a proof that it is measure preserving  see the the nice argument in Sec. 2.3 of the book *Ergodic theory* by  K. Petersen, Cambridge University Press, 1983..